# How to use multi-response models in pls package?

Tags: r

> The formula argument should be a symbolic formula of the form response ~ terms, where response is the name of the **response vector or matrix (for multi-response models)** and terms is the name of one or more predictor matrices, usually separated by +, e.g., water ~ FTIR or y ~ X + Z.

```
train_data=as.matrix(spec1)
train_content=(as.matrix(real1))

fmla <- as.formula(paste('train_content','~','train_data'))  
obj.pls=cppls(fmla,ncomp=100,validation = "CV",method = "cppls")
```

the error is:

> ```
> Error in model.frame.default(formula = fmla) : 
> parameter'train_content'type(NULL)is incorrect
> ```

So,how to use multi-response models in pls package with R?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that there is something wrong with your train_content object.

Comment: Please provide your `spec1` and `real1`

Comment: @useR 

> class(spec1)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

> typeof(spec1)
[1] "list"

> class(real1)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: @user24067 not the `class`, but the actual data used that produced the error. You can do this by copy and pasting the output of `dput(spec1)` and `dput(real1)`